# /dev/tty: no such device or address - only in a script

Tags: bash, ssh, tty

I'm pulling my hair out over this. I've looked over all of the google results for /dev/tty : no such device or address, none of them apply to what I am doing / none of the solutions are successful.

I have a script that ssh'es into another machine (using public keys) and runs itself (with different parameters - it doesn't loop). Call this rpmInstallScript.bash

At one point in the script, it runs rpm -ivh to install some RPM packages. During the install of one of these packages, a file is put in /var/tmp called rpm-tmp.[6 random characters]

This file is a script, and I guess it's executed at some point during the rpm install.

In the script, there are multiple occurrences of

```
echo [something] > /dev/tty
```

or

```
echo [something] | tee [something] > /dev/tty.
```

All of these occurrences fail with /dev/tty: no such device or address. If I ssh into the machine manually and either rpm the packages myself, run the rpm-tmp script or run rpmInstallscript.bash, it works fine.

I am connecting to the remote machine with ssh -t, therefore there should be a tty, correct?

I don't see why this isn't working, especially because doing it manually, even without the -t option, works fine. The only thing I can think of is that it's not an interactive session - but /dev/tty should still exist, correct?

Edit - the error results from :

```
ssh -t root@[machine] -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null <<DONE
./rpmInstallScript.bash
```

where rpmInstallScript.bash runs rpm -ivh, the resulting script placed in /var/tmp uses >/dev/tty - this is what fails

Edit again :
using -tt gives :

```
tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Only when running from a script - manually running ssh -tt and then echo test >/dev/tty works fine.

I can only assume this is a failure to force-create a tty.

Is there any other way to 'generate' a tty? Can I just spoof it by making a file called /dev/tty?

Comment: The `-t` option **should** have solved this. Try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so you can see all the things it does. Maybe something is checking an environment variable like `$TERM` and disconnecting from the terminal when this isn't set.

Comment: I know what it's doing - that's not the problem. It's trying to send output to /dev/tty. The issue is that it's claiming the device doesn't exist

Comment: I know that. I'm hoping that you'll see something *before* that which explains how it's getting disconnected from the terminal.

Comment: ah - I see what you mean, I'll give that a go

Comment: If you're still having trouble, please edit your question to include the relevant parts of this script.

Comment: Barmar - I tried using set -x, however that is only local to the script that is being run. Since the issue script is being run inside a script, which is called from the script running the ssh session - I can't set -x internally to that script. I can assume the issue is coming from the ssh session, which I definitely can't set -x on

Comment: I finally got set -x to work, none of the output is suspicious at all, just echoing and checking cases in a for loop, then an attempt to write to dev/tty.

Answer (score 3):

Try `-tt` to see if it works.

From ssh man page,

`Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.`

Comment: Edited the post - this failed with another [related] error