# How to 'set -x' for scripts other than my own

Tags: linux, bash

I am still dealing with a bug from [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1087382/) which has gone unanswered because I can't get debugging information.

I have scripts running other scripts and I need to see how the tty is getting disconnected from the terminal.

Is there any way to 'set -x' globally? I can't set it in the problem script because it is dynamically generated, not by me, but I'd like to see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Invoke Bash with a shell option set

According to the [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash) section of the Bash manual,

> All of the single-character options used with the set builtin (see The Set
>   Builtin) can be used as options when the shell is invoked

This means you can run a Bash script with the `xtrace` option set by directly invoking `bash` with the `-x` option and the file name of the script as an argument, e.g.,

```
bash -x /path/to/script
```

---

#### Configure shell option for all shell scripts

When you say “global”, I presume you want it set the `xtrace` option for all non-interactive invocations of Bash. To do this, set the `BASH_ENV` environment variable to a suitable filename and then create that file with `set -x` as its contents:

```
export BASH_ENV=~/.bash_env
echo set -x > ~/.bash_env
```

From the man page:

> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example,
>   it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment, expands its value
>   if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to
>   read and execute.